# AlertDialog with animations

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog that coming in and out with animations, and I want to add buttons to it, how can I do it?

Here is my AlertDialog code:

```
private void openPopUP() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Game Paused");
    builder.setMessage("Check out the transition!");
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations =
    R.style.dialog_animation;
    dialog.show(); 
}
```

Here is my style code:

```
    <resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>
   <style name="dialog_animation">


<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>


<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>


</style>
</resources>
```

Here is my anim folder files:

Slide in left:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


        android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"


        android:duration="500" />
```

Slide out right:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
```

I need to add 3 buttons inside the alertdialog, how can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `builder.setPositiveButton(String title, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)` and then `builder.setNeutralButton(...)` and finally `builder.setNegativeButton(...)`